# Как вызвать одну функцию с разными аргументами несколько раз?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть 2 popup на сайте, для их вызова я написал функцию, которая открывает попап, в функцию передается 2 аргумента - id попапа и класс кнопки вызова, так как по разным кнопкам вызываются разные попапы.

Теперь я вызываю первый раз функцию с аргументами для первого попапап и второй раз вызываю функцию с аргументами для второго попапа, но при клике на любую из двух кнопок вызывающих попапы открывается один и тот же попап, функция которого вызывается позже.

Сам код:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
function popupCall($popupID, $btnClass) {
    $btn3 = $($btnClass);
    $popup3 = $($popupID);
    $close = $('.cr-popup__close');

    $btn3.click(function () {
        $popup3.addClass('is-active')
    })

    $close.click(function () {
        $popup3.removeClass('is-active')
    })

    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        if ($popup3.hasClass('is-active')) {
            if ($popup3.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $popup3.removeClass('is-active')
            }
        }
    });
}

popupCall('#need-help-popup', '.need-help__link');
popupCall('#become-member-popup', '.become-member__btn');
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function popupCall($popupID, $btnClass) {
    var $btn3 = $($btnClass);
    var $popup3 = $($popupID);
    var $close = $('.cr-popup__close');

    ...
```

Без `var` у Вас получились глобальные переменные. Таким образом в `$popup3` хранится последнее значение.

Comment: спасибо, получилось